# How can I use countif on a none continuous range?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large set of data in an excel spreadsheet.  I want to count for each row the number of values **in specific columns**, highlighted below, that are greater than zero.  How can I do this?

[image: screenshot of rows to be counted]

I have tried `COUNTIF()`, which will not accept a non-continuous range and `COUNTIFS()` giving the ranges and criteria separately, however this gives an error for `>0` as a criteria.  I also thought of using named ranges for this, but I need to be able to copy the formula easily for 40 or so rows.

- `=COUNTIF((DN6, DV6),>0)` is not accepted by Excel (gives #VALUE with "0" rather than ">0")
- `=COUNTIFS(DN6, >0, DV6, >0)`is not accepted by Excel (but works with "0" rather than ">0")

Can anyone suggest anything that might work instead?

Comment: What is the exact formula you're using when attempting `COUNTIFS()`?

Comment: Since I can't edit my comment on here yet: do you want to count that row once if A, C, and E are all greater than zero or count how many are greater than zero in each row? Essentially what is the expected outcome? Can you give us an example?

Comment: @Taelsin updated with examples.  The formula should count the number of **cells** in each selection that are >0

Comment: @MátéJuhász you are correct I did not think it through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not a situation where I'd use `COUNTIF`, you can simply do:

`=(DN6>0)+(DV6>0)`

How it works:

- `DN6>0` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`
- when booleans are used in arithmetic formulas `FALSE` is automatically converted to `0` and `TRUE` to `1`
  (there is also automatic conversion in the other way, in logical formulas `0` is converted to `FALSE`, all other numbers to `TRUE`)

---

Using `COUNTIF` would make sense in case you'd have ranges consisting of multiple cells, e.g.:

`=COUNTIF(DK6:DN6,">0")+COUNTIF(DV6:EA6,">0")`

Comment: That formula works perfectly - thank you!  Could you explain what it's doing though?  I don't understand the operators in the way they are being used.

Comment: Please see my update, I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

As I only needed to calculate the values once rather than dynamically, I ended up copying and pasting the individual columns into a new sheet.  From there I could just use `COUNTIF()` on the now continuous range.

This may be faster than [Máté's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1168886/118913) if like me you only need to calculate the value once and have a lot of columns that would require a lot of typing to use the `(Cell>0)` method suggested above.